# Foreign_key_check fails with workbench export and phpmyadmin

Tags: import, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, export, mysql-workbench

I've created a database structure with mysql workbench.
Now i'm trying to export and import it to Phpmyadmin.

But i'm getting the error 150. (foreign key constrain)
When exporting it without the foreign keys it works perfect!

Workbench standard exports with:

```
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
at the beginning

and
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
at the end.
```

But this doesn't work for some reason. phpmyadmin ignores it.
also replacing it with the simple version:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and even not resetting it at the end of the file doesn't help.

anybody know how to export / import from to workbench and phpmyadmin with foreign keys?

Comment: I have also had this problem and it only happened with a very old version of phpMyAdmin, but my guess is that it might have to do with the client library version or some version of mysql

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem and since many of my customers use that, I created a bash script around mysqldump so I don't forget to do this.

```
function phpmyadmin_safe_dump
{
    printf "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;\n";
    mysqldump $1;
    printf "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;\n";
}
```